# Basic認証を設定する方法を教えてください。

Tags: wordpress, 認証認可

会員ページでベーシック認証を設定する方法

ベーシック認証をかける意図は、
会員様以外の人のログインを阻止するためです。

つまり登録してもらった会員様はスムーズにログイン、登録していない非会員はベーシック認証、なるべくこのようにしたいのです。

かなり長時間ログインしてないとベーシック認証が発動する状態にする、
よく会員サイトを見ている会員様はベーシック認証が発動しない。

以前のプログラマーの方は、設定をしてくれていたみたいで、何か方法があるのではないかとは思っております。

私自身そのような設定をした経験がないので、ご教授頂けますと大変有り難いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ここでいう「ログイン」とはベーシック認証で認証されることを指していますか？　それとも何かしら別のログイン方法でしょうか。

Comment: そういうの、私の知る限りですが、あり得ないです。そもそも「ベーシック認証」とは何か分かってますか？ 検索などで調べて知識を得て、質問を見直すことをお勧めします。

Comment: 「会員はスムーズにログイン」はベーシック認証とは別の方法かのように読み取れます。また、非会員は一律ログイン不可ではなく「ベーシック認証」という仕様も一般的ではなく理解し辛いです。

Comment: ベーシック認証は分かります。しかし、以前のプログラマーが以前の会員HPで設定できたようです。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　今回は、また別の新しい会員サイトページで作成し、同じように実装して欲しいとのこと要望がありました。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　①非会員は新規登録専用のページにアクセスするとベーシック認証が発動する。

②登録した会員は、新規登録専用のページサイト以外で全体サイトページにベーシック認証を発動させない。（この時はログイン画面のみ表示されています）

③会員が長期間ログインしていない場合、ログインするとベーシック認証がかかる。

このような実装方法は可能でしょうか。

AIやGPTに問い合わせてみましたら、.htaccessファイルを作成するとか、PHPで作成する方法があると結果が出ているのですが信じていいのか分からないです。

まだプログラミングを学んで1年も経たず、知識不足で大変申し訳ございませんが、何か方法があるか、もしはっきりとそのような方法がないとならば、正直仰ってくだると助かります。

よろしくお願いいたします！

Comment: 質問者さんの思ってるベーシック認証と、普通に世間一般でいうベーシック認証とが違うようで、話が通じてない気がします。「ベーシック認証は分かります」とのことですが、説明していただけますか？

Comment: ベーシック認証というよりは、ログイン状態を保持する方が主眼なのでは？ おそらくこの辺の記事とかを取っ掛かりにして調べていけば良いと思われます。[「ログイン状態を保存する」は通常何をしてる？](https://teratail.com/questions/335730), [安全なウェブサイトの作り方 - 1.4 セッション管理の不備](https://www.ipa.go.jp/security/vuln/websecurity/session-management.html), [Cookieによるログイン認証](https://zenn.dev/masahiro_toba/books/3daf7dc0d5dfd7/viewer/e1322e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

なんとなく意図はわからないでもないですが、

- 対象のシステムの構成がほとんどわからない
- 質問内容が要件を正確にすべて網羅しているとはいえない気がする

ので正確かつ理解可能な回答を得るのは難しいと思います。

実物を見て要件確認して不足点をヒアリングして･･･ということができればおそらくそんなに難しい話でもないと思うので、知識がある人に(お金払って)頼んだ方がよいかと。

--

イメージレベルでは

- ｢常連さん｣にはどこかでCookieを食べさせる
- そのCookieの有無でBasic認証をかけるかどうか制御する
- 利用のたびに有効期限を更新すれば「しばらく使ってない人」は再びBasic認証を要求する

でいいような気がしますが、前記の通り構成も正確な要件もわからないので具体的な設定方法は提示できません。

Answer (score 1):

質問者さんの思ってるベーシック認証と、普通に世間一般でいうベーシック認証とが違うようで、話が通じてない気がしますが・・・

> ①非会員は新規登録専用のページにアクセスするとベーシック認証が発動する。
> ②登録した会員は、新規登録専用のページサイト以外で全体サイトページにベーシック認証を発動させない。（この時はログイン画面のみ表示されています）
> ③会員が長期間ログインしていない場合、ログインするとベーシック認証がかかる。 このような実装方法は可能でしょうか。

> もしはっきりとそのような方法がないとならば、正直仰ってくだると助かります。

普通に世間一般でいうベーシック認証でアクセス制限をした場合、ユーザーがブラウザを立ち上げてアクセスすると、一番最初のアクセスに対しては以下の画像のようなユーザー名とパスワードを入力してログインを促すダイアログが出ます (画像は Chrome 121.0.6167.161 のもの。ブラウザによって多少異なります)。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

有効なユーザー名とパスワードを入力して［ログイン］ボタンをクリックするとログインでき、ブラウザをシャットダウンしない限り要求のたび自動的に認証が行われるようになります。

しかし、ブラウザをシャットダウンした後でブラウザを立ち上げてアクセスすると、再度上の画像のダイアログが表示され、ログイン操作が必要になります。

なので、普通に世間一般でいうベーシック認証で上の ① ～ ③ のようなことはできません。